# Shopify Customization - How do I put all product images in a scrollable centre column?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, shopify

I am web developer who is currently working on a project which requires me to do something much more advanced than anything I've ever done before, so if anyone could help it would be heaps appreciated! :) At the moment 1 product image is displayed as the main product image, and there is a sidebar with the rest of the product images. I need them to all be part of one scrollable column like the example below.

Here is an example of what I need to achieve

https://www.ssense.com/en-au/men/product/vetements/black-genetically-modified-volunteer-puffer-jacket/2233187

Comment: I am not sure which theme you chose to start with but can you create 2 collection 1st item with only one product and 2nd goes underneath of it so it looks like the site. rest of stuff can be achieve with css and liquid(? not sure it's been half year)

Comment: For that scroll effect where the other columns stay fixed, you can use Sticky-kit: http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/   , To get all of the images in liquid for your column, you'll need to use a liquid for loop on the array product.images to grab each image: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/iteration-tags#for